# R: condense indexes

Tags: r

I have a vector like the following:

```
xx <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

I want to find the indexes that have ones and combine them together. In this case, I want the output to look like 1 6 and 11 14 in a 2x2 matrix. My vector is actually very long so I can't do this by hand. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the question originally had a tag 'bioinformatics' I'll mention the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) package *[IRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html)* (and it's companion for ranges on genomes *[GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html)*)

```
> library(IRanges)
> xx <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
> sl = slice(Rle(xx), 1)
> sl
Views on a 14-length Rle subject

views:
    start end width
[1]     1   6     6 [1 1 1 1 1 1]
[2]    11  14     4 [1 1 1 1]
```

which could be coerced to a matrix, but that would often not be convenient for whatever the next step is

```
> matrix(c(start(sl), end(sl)), ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]   11   14
```

Other operations might start on the `Rle`, e.g.,

```
> xx = c(2,2,2,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,4,4,1,1)
> r = Rle(xx)
> m = cbind(start(r), end(r))[runValue(r) != 0,,drop=FALSE]
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    4    6
[3,]   11   12
[4,]   13   14
```

**See the help page `?Rle`** for the full flexibility of the `Rle` class; to go from a matrix like that above to a new Rle as asked in the comment below, one might create a new Rle of appropriate length and then subset-assign using an IRanges as index

```
> r = Rle(0L, max(m))
> r[IRanges(m[,1], m[,2])] = 1L
> r
integer-Rle of length 14 with 3 runs
  Lengths: 6 4 4
  Values : 1 0 1
```

One could expand this to a full vector

```
> as(r, "integer")
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

but often it's better to continue the analysis on the Rle. The class is very flexible, so one way of going from `xx` to an integer vector of 1's and 0's is

```
> as(Rle(xx) > 0, "integer")
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Again, though, it often makes sense to stay in Rle space. And [Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121205/r-matrix-to-indexes/17121362#17121362)'s answer to your separate question is probably best of all.

**Performance** (speed) is important, although in this case I think the Rle class provides a lot of flexibility that would weigh against poor performance, and ending up at a matrix is an unlikely end-point for a typical analysis. Nonetheles the IRanges infrastructure *is* performant

```
eddi <- function(xx)
    matrix(which(diff(c(0,xx,0)) != 0) - c(0,1),
           ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

iranges = function(xx) {
    sl = slice(Rle(xx), 1)
    matrix(c(start(sl), end(sl)), ncol=2)
}

iranges.1 = function(xx) {
    r = Rle(xx)
    cbind(start(r), end(r))[runValue(r) != 0, , drop=FALSE]
}
```

with

```
> xx = sample(c(0, 1), 1e5, TRUE)
> microbenchmark(eddi(xx), iranges(xx), iranges.1(xx), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
      eddi(xx)  45.88009  46.69360  47.67374 226.15084 234.8138    10
   iranges(xx) 112.09530 114.36889 229.90911 292.84153 294.7348    10
 iranges.1(xx)  31.64954  31.72658  33.26242  35.52092 226.7817    10
```

Comment: What if I have xx=c(2,2,2,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,4,4,1,1) and I want to get 1 3, 4 6, 11 12, and 13 14 in a 4x2 matrix?

Comment: @user1938809 I've added that to the response.

Comment: May I ask how to go from 1 3, 4 6, 11 12, and 13 14 to the vector form (1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1) without any loop assuming you know the vector size is 14. It is slow using loop. Thanks.

Comment: @user1938809 check out the help page ?Rle for what can be done; I've added some more for your specific question

Answer (score 5):

Something like this, maybe?

```
if (xx[1] == 1) {
    rr <- cumsum(c(0, rle(xx)$lengths))
} else {
    rr <- cumsum(rle(xx)$lengths)
}
if (length(rr) %% 2 == 1) {
    rr <- head(rr, -1)
}
oo <- matrix(rr, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
oo[, 1] <- oo[, 1] + 1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]   11   14
```

This edit takes care of cases where 1) the vector starts with a "0" rather than a "1" and 2) where the number of consecutive occurrences of 1's are odd/even. For ex: `xx <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another, short one:

```
cbind(start = which(diff(c(0, xx)) == +1),
      end   = which(diff(c(xx, 0)) == -1))
#      start end
# [1,]     1   6
# [2,]    11  14
```

I tested on a very long vector and it is marginally slower than using `rle`. But more readable IMHO. If speed were really a concern, you could also do:

```
xx.diff <- diff(c(0, xx, 0))
cbind(start = which(head(xx.diff, -1) == +1),
      end   = which(tail(xx.diff, -1) == -1))
#      start end
# [1,]     1   6
# [2,]    11  14
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that's built upon the others' ideas, and is a bit shorter and faster:

```
matrix(which(diff(c(0,xx,0)) != 0) - c(0,1), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    6
#[2,]   11   14
```

I didn't test the non-base solution, but here's a comparison of base ones:

```
xx = sample(c(0,1), 1e5, T)
microbenchmark(arun(xx), flodel(xx), flodel.fast(xx), eddi(xx))
#Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#        arun(xx) 14.021134 14.181134 14.246415 14.332655 15.220496   100
#      flodel(xx) 12.885134 13.186254 13.248334 13.432974 14.367695   100
# flodel.fast(xx)  9.704010  9.952810 10.063691 10.211371 11.108171   100
#        eddi(xx)  7.029448  7.276008  7.328968  7.439528  8.361609   100
```

Comment: FWIW I added IRanges timings to my response.

Comment: nice! that's actually pretty surprising